# Hibernate parallelize with pagination

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pagination

I recently migrated a project that uses Hibernate to AWS from a local server. When this happened, the query went from taking 1.3 seconds to 18 seconds. I'm convinced that this is because each call is taking longer to access the server, which adds up and increases the run time dramatically.

My thinking of how to fix this was to add pagination and parallelize so that while Hibernate is making the query to get all of the data I have another thread just reading off the first n entries and returning them to the page. But, everything I've read online about this indicates that pagination works still by making the entire query and then just putting everything into a list with `query.setFirstResults(int)` and `query.setMaxResults(int)`.

As per this example taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

```
String hql = "FROM Employee";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setFirstResult(1);
query.setMaxResults(10);
List results = query.list();
```

So, is this approach possible?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'm convinced that this is because each call is taking longer to access the server". The web server? The database server? I'd try to figure out the real reason instead of being convinced by things that are probably not true.

Comment: So, is this approach possible? did you try atleast coding it? If not working then show us error logs.

Comment: About the HQL:  try checking the generated SQL statement. I have some experience with Oracle, and in my scenario, the code you posted would generate a SQL that would restrict the number of rows returned by the Oracle instance. Now, considering the problem as a whole, if you try running several parallel queries it has a chance that all of them will be very slow too. I would try to be sure about what is really causing this trouble.